# issue with an array - returning chaotic value

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have array zoneVibrateCounts[]:-

```
2017-12-11 06:10:22.815835-0800 slate[7431:2975293] Array: (
4,
1,
1,
10,
1,
1,
1,
1
)
```

And I try accessing its first element like so:-

```
NSArray<NSNumber*> *currcount = [SettingsManager shared].zoneVibrateCounts;
value = currcount[0]
```

Although, the return value im getting is 19, not 4. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe using `return @[@19];` for returning 19?

Comment: Can you add the code you‘re using to verify what type you got back? And maybe also the code you use to create the array add an item to it? This should work, so the error must be somewhere else in this code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your value variable data type is int or NSInteger so that only you got this 19. Try the following code,

```
value = [currcount[0] intValue] or value = [currcount[0] integerValue];
```